# Rails error "jquery.js isn't in paths .... "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying out a Q&A application written in rails 3.1 on my Ubuntu system. After I run the server (rails server), and enter the localhost:3000 url in the browser, I'm getting the following error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js isn't in paths:
(...."displays a list of paths including /$home/myapp/jquery-rails/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.14/vendor/assets/javascripts".....).
```

I did `bundle update` and it installed the jquery.js and all other .js files in that last path. But I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestions about what I might be doing wrong here?

P.S. When I enter the URL localhost:3000, it actually tries to open the URL: http://localhost:3000/session/new. Must be some application specific logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove everything in your /tmp directory and restart the Rails app.
Fixes it for me.